# Scrollbars to top and bottom using jScrollPane

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane, scrollbars

I'm using jScrollPane http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com to convert my default scrollbars to an HTML scruture that I can skin with CSS.

Now I'm trying to simulate two horizontal scrollbars (in sync) to TOP and BOTTOM of a table.
Is this something I can achieve using jScrollPane?

Thanks,

Greg

Answer (score 0):

jScrollPane will only create one of these scrollbars for you (you can choose whether you want it at the top or the bottom using CSS). You could manually create the other scrollbar (prehaps by cloning the one jScrollPane created and then use the [jScrollPane API](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/api.html) and the [jScrollPane events](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/events.html) to keep the scrollbars synced.